# How to change link from example.com/products/productfamily/product

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working on a site. The site manager wants me to change the url from example.com/products/productfamily/product to example.com/lighting/productfamily/product while still showing the same page, it isn't a redirect.

I already have tried to do this with .htacces although I am not completely sure how this works. The site keeps working but the part products is not changed to lighting.

-

I hope someone will be able to tell me if I can change just the url while still showing the same page and if so, how to do this.

Comment: And how do you expect us to help with your code if you do not post your code?

Answer (score 0):

This probably is what you are looking for... Your question is vague in a few aspects, so you probably will have to tweak this for your needs. But it should point you into the right direction:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?products/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /lightning/$1/$2 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?lightning/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /products/$1/$2 [END]
```

It is a good idea to start out with a 302 temporary redirection and only change that to a 301 permanent redirection later, once you are certain everything is correctly set up. That prevents caching issues while trying things out...

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).